# Omit joining lines in matplotlib plot e.g. y = tan(x)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the graph `y = tan(x)` and I want to remove the vertical lines (see below).

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Choose evenly spaced x intervals
x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.1)

# plot y = tan(x)
plt.plot(x, np.tan(x))

# Set the range of the axes
plt.axis([-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, -2, 2])

# Include a title
plt.title('y = tan(x)')

# Optional grid-lines
plt.grid()

# Show the graph
plt.show()
```

Here is the graph (including unwanted vertical lines):

[image]

Can I remove the vertical lines without setting appropriate gaps into the x intervals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check the difference between successive data points using [`diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and then identify where the difference is negative and replace these values with `NaN` to create a visual break in the plotted line

```
# Compute the tangent for each point
y = np.tan(x)

# Insert a NaN where the difference between successive points is negative
y[:-1][np.diff(y) < 0] = np.nan

# Plot the resulting discontinuous line
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `y[:-1][np.diff(y) < 0] = np.nan` is more comprehensible?!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yea that's a little clearer and likely more performant. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know you could input values as NaN to make a discontinuous curve.

Comment: More generally `y[:-1][abs(np.diff(y)) > n ] = np.nan` would be useful to remove vertical lines from a graph like `y = sec(x)` where the difference between successive points can be positive or negative. This would take a bit of tinkering to set n to an appropriate value.

Comment: @Astrophe Right. There really isn't a great general solution that will work for all functions with discontinuities like this.

Answer (score 3):

One could use the definition of the tangent to filter out those points where the cosine of `x` is close enough to `0`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 666)
y = np.tan(x)

y[np.abs(np.cos(x)) <= np.abs(np.sin(x[1]-x[0]))] = np.nan

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(-3,3)

plt.show()
```

This works for equally spaced data only.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to have the overhead of a more powerful mathematical program, [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org) can help with this:

```
plot(tan(x),(x,-2*pi,2*pi),detect_poles=True,ymin=-2,ymax=2,ticks=[pi/2,None],tick_formatter=pi)
```

[image]

(The little opening at the origin is something I've not seen before, hopefully fixed again soon.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of tan, sin/cos. The vertical asymptotes will happen when cos = 0, so write a conditional statement such as:
    if cos(x) != 0:
        plt.plot(x, np.tan(x))

Comment: That will not work out of the box. Even `cos(np.pi/2.)` is unequal to `0` numerically.