# How to plot tan(x) with pyplot and numpy

Tags: python, discrete-mathematics

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10000)
plt.plot(x, np.tan(x))
plt.show()
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

**The result I get:**

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two issues, I think. The first is about `np.linspace`, the second about plotting.

`np.linspace` defaults to returning 50 elements within the given range. So you're plotting 50 points over `(0, 10000)`, meaning the elements are very widely spaced. Also, that range doesn't make a whole lot of sense for the tangent function. I'd use something much smaller, probably +/- 2 * pi.

The second issue is the y-axis. The tangent function diverges to infinity quite quickly at multiples of `pi/2`, which means you're missing a lot of the interesting behavior by plotting the full y-range. The code below should solve these issues.

```
x = np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
plt.plot(x, np.tan(x))
plt.ylim(-5, 5)
```

You should see something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, increasing n elements in linspace helped.

Answer (score 2):

bnaecker's suggestion of .linspace and the responses from [Omit joining lines in matplotlib plot e.g. y = tan(x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837910/omit-joining-lines-in-matplotlib-plot-e-g-y-tanx/42838017#42838017) helped generate the following approach:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# .linspace arguments are (start, end, number_of_steps)
x = np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.tan(x)

# This operation inserts a NaN where the difference between successive points is negative
# NaN means "Not a Number" and NaNs are not plotted or connected
# I found this by doing a search for "How to plot tan(x) in matplotlib without the connecting lines between asymtotes"
y[:-1][np.diff(y) < 0] = np.nan

# show grid
plt.grid()

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("$tan(x)$")

# Set the x and y axis cutoffs
plt.ylim(-10,10)
plt.xlim(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi)

# x_labels in radians
# For a more programmatic approach to radians, see https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/units/radian_demo.html
radian_multiples = [-2, -3/2, -1, -1/2, 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2]
radians = [n * np.pi for n in radian_multiples]
radian_labels = ['$-2\pi$', '$-3\pi/2$', '$\pi$', '$-\pi/2$', '0', '$\pi/2$', '$\pi$', '$3\pi/2$', '$2\pi$']

plt.xticks(radians, radian_labels)

plt.title("$y = tan(x)$", fontsize=14)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar  Solution I found while search it may be helpful for other's

```
t = np.arange(0.0, 1, 0.01)
s = np.tan(t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)
ax.set(xlabel='radians', ylabel='tan(x)',
       title='Tangent Plot')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

https://www.includehelp.com/python/plotting-trigonometric-functions.aspx

See above link for more details