# Disable automatic connection of lines matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graph

I have created a program to draw a graph of a function in a given range. However, in the case of some functions, such as tan, there is a problem with empty spaces. matplotlib automatically connects all points with lines.

[image: Program]

Is there any way to prevent these connections?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to just use the plot function multiple times, once for each group of points you want to plot. Either that or insert an np.nan in the place where you want a break, because it does skip missing points.

Comment: You need to increase the number of discretization points in the x direction and then use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42838056/2329968